# SQL Concat and intvalue

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have one index field and one subindex field that i Need to concatenate to get a id.

I cant just concat the two field because then it can give double values...

Say i got index 18 and  subindex 8 it will give me 188 and that will also index 1 togheter with subindex 88 give me.

Becuase of that i want too add a 0 in the subindex field where the values are from 1-9.

Can someone pls help me with the Syntax for this. Language is MySQL and the both tables have int values..

Before subindex i have to add a 0 if the value is 1-9, `CONCAT (`index`,`subindex`) AS` indexID

Comment: ...and what happens when `subindex` grows to 3 digits?  (If your answer is "add another `0`, well...)  If the id is for use inside your DB, why not just leave it as 2 columns?  If it's for use _outside_ your db, you should most likely be generating a specific (single) id for that purpose (or possibly formatting the concatenation different, if that's where the id values came from in the first place, but then they're most likely **strings**, and should have been entered/stored as such).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE Combined with CONCAT as below.

[WORKING FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf4f68/6)

```
SELECT
`INDEX`,`SUB_INDEX`,
(
    CONCAT
    ((CASE WHEN `INDEX` <10
         THEN CONCAT ('0' , `INDEX`)
         ELSE `INDEX`
      END)
    ,
    (CASE WHEN SUB_INDEX <10
        THEN CONCAT ('0' , `SUB_INDEX`)
         ELSE SUB_INDEX 
      END)
     )
) AS ID
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONCAT ( 
  if(`index`<10,CONCAT ('0' , `INDEX`),`INDEX`), 
  if(`subindex`<10,CONCAT ('0' , `subindex`),`subindex`)) as ID from Table1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86a2f/6)

Comment: please add some more explanation to your code, so that others can easier understand your solution.